# Automate the boring stuff with python - Character picture grid

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, array

## Character Picture Grid

Say you have a list of lists where each value in the inner lists is a one-character string, like this:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

You can think of `grid[x][y]` as being the character at the x- and y-coordinates of a “picture” drawn with text characters. The (0, 0) origin will be in the upper-left corner; the x-coordinates increase going right, and the y-coordinates increase going down.

Copy the previous grid value, and write code that uses it to print the image.

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

My solution:

```
def logic_grid(grid):
    for x in range(6):
        for y in range(9):
            if y < 8:
                print(grid[y][x], end='')
            else:
                print(grid[y][x])

def main():
    grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
            ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
            ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
            ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
            ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
            ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
            ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
            ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
            ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
    start = logic_grid(grid)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: As it is, your grid represents a list of columns. Would it also be acceptable to rearrange the data to have a list of rows instead, or is this a hard requirement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In Python, you rarely need to iterate using indexes**. Iterate directly
over the values themselves, not their indexes. [The latter is what programmers
working in poorer languages have to do.]

**Question the assignment**. In my opinion, the function should not
take a grid and print it. Rather, it should return the grid as a string. The
latter is more flexible and more in line with the general principle of
organizing programs around data-oriented, side-effect-free functions.

**Don't hard-code the function to one specific grid**. A key purpose of
functions is to generalize behavior so it can be reused. If the function
hardcodes the grid's dimensions, that generality disappears.

**Python iterables can be joined together into strings**. This is a basic
operation. Take advantage of it.

```python
def main():
    # Printing happens out at this level.
    grid = [...]
    print(grid_to_str(grid))
    

def grid_to_str(grid):
    # No side effects here. Just data in and data out.
    # As noted by RootTwo, we have to transpose the grid.
    return '\n'.join(
        ''.join(row)
        for row in zip(*grid)
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The grid is stored by columns. So the `'\n'.join(''.join(row) ... )` would result in a picture on its side.

Comment: @RootTwo Unfortunate. Rotate your monitor?

Comment: That call to `map` is unnecessary, you can just write `for row in zip(*grid)`.

Answer (score 5):

Currently you are making assumptions in `logic_grid` about `grid`. With the current setup it's fine, but if later `grid` becomes larger/smaller, the image will not print correctly. Instead of hardcoding in values for the array length, use `len`

```
def logic_grid(grid):
    # adding validation here to make sure grid is initialized would also be a good idea
    for x in range(len(grid[0])):
        for y in range(len(grid)):
            if y < len(grid)-1:
                print(grid[y][x], end='')
            else:
                print(grid[y][x])
```

I would also suggest using a better function name as `logic_grid` doesn't do anything besides printing, so something like `print_grid` or `display_grid` would describe what the function does much better.

Comment: How do you mean validation?

Comment: @JarneVercruysse validation like `type(grid) is list and len(grid)>0)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `zip` to transpose the itearble of iterables. Like this:

```
print('\n'.join(''.join(i) for i in zip(*grid)))
```

(and this code above is *the* solution)

Another example: dot product of two math vectors with zip

```
dot_product = lambda x,y:sum(i*j for i,j in zip(x,y))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need zip() and you don't need len(). Just concatenate each row to a string then print the row:

```
for row in grid:
    the_row = ''
    for i in row:
        the_row += i
    print(the_row)
```

Comment: You need zip because the data is sideways. If you try this way the image will be on its side.